# How to pass an array of components with required props in React with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a generic filtering component which accepts an array of components (component that handles gender filtering, age filtering, etc...) with required props. For example, Filter component will handle the logic behind and will render any children components that accepts `changeUrlSearch`. I've tried several ways but nothing works. The problem is that it won't throw an error if I pass component that does not implement this method.

Is there even a way to do this?
This is my approach..

```
interface ChildrenProps {
  hello: (...any) => any;
}

interface FiltersProps<T> {
  filters: T;
}

function Filters<T extends React.FC<ChildrenProps>[]>({ filters }: FiltersProps<T>) {
  return (
    <>
      {filters.map((Component) => (
        <Component hello={() => {}} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Filters;
```

And this is render of the `Filters` components. However it does not throw an error even when these components does not accept `hello` function as a props.

```
<Filters filters={[DateTypeFilter, DateFilter]} />
```

I created a CodeSandbox project with possible solution. However it doesn't feel right to me. Why can't I use `React.FC`?

[image: Edit React Typescript]

Comment: I've created a sandbox with possible solution. However it does not feel right to me. Why can't i use `React.FC`?
https://codesandbox.io/s/n3138x65p0

Comment: you have written a class component in the sandbox, `FC` is a type for functional component

Comment: Ouch it's completely different Sandbox O.o I'll fix that

Comment: @Agney It's fixed.